# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function dispatch() on null

Tags: php, magento2

Link for complete code. [Download from here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bZ4dYFOcHnZcQuiiOTX_E4hOy3Gi0qlT/view?usp=sharing)

I am learning Magento 2 And now stuck on an error. 
This is the error message when called my frontend view block.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function dispatch() on null in C:\wamp64\www\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection.php:541 Stack trace: #0 C:\wamp64\www\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb.php(577): Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection->_beforeLoad() #1 C:\wamp64\www\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb.php(565): Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb->loadWithFilter(false, false) #2 C:\wamp64\www\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\Data\Collection.php(333): Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb->load() #3 C:\wamp64\www\magento2\app\code\Mastering\SampleModule\Block\Hello.php(19): Magento\Framework\Data\Collection->getItems() #4 C:\wamp64\www\magento2\app\code\Mastering\SampleModule\view\frontend\templates\hello.phtml(7): Mastering\SampleModule\Block\Hello->getItems() #5 C:\wamp64\www\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php.php(59): include('C:\\wamp in C:\wamp64\www\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection.php on line 541
```

Here is my code where I stuck in Hello.php class.

```
<?php

namespace Mastering\SampleModule\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Mastering\SampleModule\Model\ResourceModel\Item\CollectionFactory;
class Hello extends Template {

    private $collectionFactory;

    public function __construct(Template\Context $context, CollectionFactory $collectionFactory, array $data = [] ){
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getItems() {
        return $this->collectionFactory->create()->getItems();
    }

}
```

> Collection.php class

```
namespace Mastering\SampleModule\Model\ResourceModel\Item;

use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;
use Mastering\SampleModule\Model\Item;
use Mastering\SampleModule\Model\ResourceModel\Item as ItemResource;

class Collection extends AbstractCollection {

    protected $_idFieldName = 'id';

    public function __construct() {
        $this->_init( Item::class, ItemResource::class );

    }
}
```

> app\code\Mastering\SampleModule\view\frontend\layout\mastering_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block name="mastering_hello" class="Mastering\SampleModule\Block\Hello" template="hello.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> Hello.phtml view file

```
<?php
/** @var \Mastering\SampleModule\Block\Hello $block */

//var_dump($block->getItems());
?>

<?php foreach($block->getItems() as $item ): ?>
    <p>
        <?php echo $item->getName(); ?>: <?php $item->getDescription(); ?>
    </p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: I am also facing similar issue.

Answer (score -1):

In your Collection.php class, try to write contructor with one _ not two __, your code will be like this:

```
public function _construct() {
    $this->_init( Item::class, ItemResource::class );

}
```